# How to preserve the state of UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

My app writes subviews onto a `UIScrollView`. These subviews are buttons linked to other parts of the application that the user will input information onto. I want to save this data, including the subviews when the app exits. My ViewController (that stores the scroll view and all its subviews) has a Restoration ID in storyboard. How do I use this? This is what I have so far:

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldSaveApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder {

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldRestoreApplicationState:(NSCoder *)coder {

    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
    [coder encodeObject:self.scrollView forKey:@"scrollView"]; 
}

- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    [super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of the `NSUserDefaults` property list?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think it will work for what I am trying to do. NSUserDefaults only takes NSCoder compliant values apparently. I can store all my subviews in an array, and then load that array into NSUserdefaults object, but then I can't redisplay them separately. Is there a way I can just "snapshot" what the app was on exit, then just reload that "snapshot" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Model View controller design (or any sane design) you don't want to physically store the view, you wan't to save some other model data in which the view can be recreated from.

Based on your short description you probably want to make your own model objects which support NSCoding and store the entire state of the object it is representing. For example:

Create a model object that stores the basic data (implement NSCoder):

```
@interface ButtonInfo : NSObject <NSCoding>
@property(nonatomic, copy)NSString* title;
@property(nonatomic, assign)CGRect frame;
@property(nonatomic, retain)UIColor* color;
@end
```

You can either generate model data from views at save time, or store the models alongside the view.

```
- (void)saveButtonInfos
```

Or:

```
- (void)saveViews:(NSArray*)views
{
   NSMutableArray* toWrite = ...
   for (view in views)
   {
      // make button info from view, add to array.
   }
}
```

Finally generate views from model data at load.

```
- (void)loadViewsFrom:(NSArray*)buttonInfos
{
    for (info in buttonInfos)
    {
      // Create new button
      // modify properties
    }
}
```